# Como insertar array dentro de otro array en php

Tags: laravel, array

no logro realizar esta inserción aun array, teniendo en cuenta que tengo este array estático de ejemplo en php. Donde pretendo visualizar el registro en una gráfica de barras con la librería canvasjs, en donde uno de sus atributos es pasarle un array como el siguiente:

```
$dataPoints = array(
                    array("label"=> "Matematicas", "y"=>22),
                    array("label"=> "Ingles", "y"=> 34),
                    array("label"=> "Fisica", "y"=> 4),
                    array("label"=> "Quimica", "y"=> 13),
                    array("label"=> "Arte", "y"=> 50)
                    );
```

Esta parte lo realizo en el controlador(por cierto estoy trabajando con laravel) pero ahora quiero obtener los datos de una base de datos. Este es mi metodo de mi controlador

```
 public function index()
    {
        $dataPoints= DB::table('materias')->get();
        return View('reporteMaterias',compact('dataPoints'));

    }
```

Ahora bien, si le paso el array estatico y lo cargo al canvarjs en uno de sus parametros de esta manera funciona correctamente:

```
data: [{
              type: "column",
              showInLegend: true,
              legendMarkerColor: "grey",
              legendText: "Materias ",
              dataPoints: @json($dataPoints)
              }]
        });
```

Entonces, volviendo al punto principal como realizaría un array dinámico pero haciendo una consulta a la base de datos para que sea dinámico? si teniendo en cuenta que esta es mi consulta `$dataPoints= DB::table('materias')->get();`
Ahora como lo paso como el array estático mencionado anteriormente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías indicar los campos de tu tabla `materias`, pero sumiendo que existe un campo `nombre` y otro llamado `campo_y`, quedaría :

```
 public function index(){
        $d= DB::table('materias')->get();
        $dataPoints = array();
        foreach ($d as $registro) {
            $dataPoints[] = array('label'=>$registro['nombre'],'y'=>$registro['campo_y']);            
        }

        return View('reporteMaterias',compact('dataPoints'));
    };
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funciono